# Extract multiple arrays from .DAT file with undefined size

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I have a device that stores three data sets in a .DAT file, they always have the same heading and number of columns, but the number of rows vary.
They are (n x 4), (m x 4), (L x 3).
I need to extract the three data sets into seperate arrays for plotting.
I have been trying to use numpy.genfromtxt and numpy.loadtxt, but the only way I can get them to work for this format is to manually define the row which each data set starts.
As I will regularly need to deal with this format I have been trying to automate it.
If someone could suggest a method which might work I would greatly appreciate it. I have attached an example file.

[example file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_viQkcWo4Z2Nlozbi1QZi1VaDQ/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a quck and dirty solution. At your file size, you might run into performance issues. If you know `m`, `n` and `L`, initialize the output vectors with the respective length.

here is the strategy: Load the whole File in a variable. Read the variable line by line. As soon as you discover a keyword, raise a flag that you are in the specific block. In the next line, read out the line to the correct variables.

```
isblock1 = isblock2 = isblock3 = False
fout = [] # construct also all the other variables that you want to collect.
with open(file, 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines() #read all the lines
for line in lines:
    if isblock1:
        (f, psd, ipj, itj) = line.split()
        fout.append(f) #do this also with the other variables
    if isblock2:
        (t1, p1, p2, p12) = line.split()
    if isblock3:
        (t2, v1, v2) = line.split()
    if 'Frequency' is in line:
        isblock1 = True
        isblock2 = isblock3 = False
    if 'Phasor' is in line:
        isblock2 = True
        isblock1 = isblock3 = False
    if 'Voltage' is in line:
        isblock3 = True
        isblock1 = isblock2 = False
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I needed, performance isn't an issue and I don't mind waiting a few extra seconds, it's quicker than manually putting in the array sizes
Thank you